# Spring-Boot project executes in IDE but not when in a JAR

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

The project current runs fine via IntelliJ. Its built with Java 11, spring-boot 2.4.3, and gradle 6.8.3
The error as I read it states that it cannot find a 'RestDriver'( which is annotated as @RestController) nor the interface 'DriverService' which has no annotations on it.  That class uses a  a class annotated with @Service 'DriverServiceImp'.
Its as if I will have to state in main where these classes are because it cannot find them.
[image: Note the project structure]

```
2021-10-21 12:04:45 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication at 856 - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'restDriver': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'driverService'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'DriverService': Lookup method resolution failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Failed to introspect Class [com.xxx.wfmDriverservice.service.DriverServiceImp] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@5c7fa833]
```

Comment: What's the complete error message and stack trace of the failure?

Comment: Please share the error log if you can .

Comment: I can pull that.

Comment: `ObjectMapper mapValue = new ObjectMapper();
   String mapperStr2 = mapValue.writeValueAsString(vdRec)              
   
logger.info(mapperStr2);            
  JSONObject dtoJSON2 = new JSONObject(mapperStr2);
   logger.info(dtoJSON2.has("value" )+"");`
So I isolated the jar failing to JSONOBJECT.
This piece of code is inside a loop where I am trying to verify if a numeric value came across. Right now Jackson will place a 0.0 if that value was never delivered into the package. Which is not ok, because I need to know if there was no value to begin with.